# Is is possible to develop website like delivery.com with wordpress?

Tags: web, wordpress

Hi I am running a delivery shop and using delivery.com for my shop.

I also want to have my own website which user can order service or choose delivery time on the website like delivery.com does.

I wonder if is it better to develop from scratch or can I use wordpress and customize it? or are there plugins or widgets I can use for my website?

Please give me some advice what will be the best way to build my website.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well technically anything is pretty much possible in Wordpress but it won't happen out of the box, unless you already have a theme in mind which serves this purpose. I won't be surprised if there is a theme out there which you can use to do this.

Personally I would build this from scratch as you would be able to build exactly what you want and you can build it with scalability in mind as well.

Wordpress tends to fall off when the site starts getting A LOT of traffic.

Check out Ruby on Rails, you would be surprised how at how simple it can be to build something like this.

Comment: Hi Thank you so much!
How about creating Wordpress template by myself?
I want to have my own design but I also need to be able to use credit card or yelp API etc. I think WP had a lot of plugin so I don't need to hard code them.

Comment: Hi yes, the Wordpress file system is really simple. You cab easily create your own template. Check out http://underscores.me/. This is a blank starter theme which you can colour in, goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

The server will go down (if) when your site will visit 1000+ persons, because one of the problem of universal script that can be used (in opinion of creators) every where is that it make 100 sql queryes to display one simple page.